# TypeError: member.roles.add is not a function (discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a bot that needs to check some things before giving/removing a role from a user, but for some reason, the `.has()`, `.some()`, `.add()` and, `.remove()` functions don't work.

Here's my code:

```
const Permissions = require('discord.js');

function isAdmin(member) {
    return member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR);
}

function hasRole(member, roleID) {
    return member.roles.some(role => role.id === roleID);
}

function giveRole(member, role) {
    member.roles.add(role)
}

function removeRole(member, role) {
    member.roles.remove(role);
}
```

Here's the full error that I get:

```
TypeError: member.roles.add is not a function
    at Object.giveRole (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\util.js:101:30)
    at Object.buttonClicked (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\commands\buttonRole\execute.js:23:14)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\index.js:101:28)
    at WebSocketManager.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:54)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1137:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:528:14)
    at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:446:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:148:22)
    at Receiver._write (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:83:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Receiver.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Github Projects\discordBots-BOK-BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1231:35)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23)
```

Comment: Can you point to the documentation upon which you're basing your implicit claim that you expect `member.roles` to *have* a `has()` function...? Are you sure you don't mean `member.roles.cache.has()`, as the [guide would indicate](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#terminology)?

Comment: I was looking at [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#checking-member-permissions) part of the docs where they do `if (member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEMBERS)) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the Discord.js classes, I found out that you cannot simply use

```
let member = interaction.member;
```

to get a guild member, but instead, you have to do

```
let member = await guild.members.fetch("ID");
```

After doing that, the `member.permissions.has`, `member.roles.add` and `member.roles.remove` functions all work!

The only function that still doesn't work is the `member.roles.some`, this is because the `GuildMemberRoleManager` class only has `add`, `set`, and `remove` functions. The `member.roles.some` function can be changed to use `member._roles` as it returns a list of Strings containing all the roles the guild member has and can be done as such:

```
function hasRole(member, roleID) {
    return member._roles.indexOf(roleID) >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Discord.js version 12, the syntax mostly changed. The cache property now contains the cache for a lot of the roles, and there is a chance you need to use a Promise and fetch it...

```js
// in an ASYNC FUNCTION
let roles = await member.roles.fetch();
return roles.some(role => role.id === roleID);
```

Comment: I'm using discord.js V13 and when I use `cache` I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')` back

Comment: with the fetch and a promise await?

Comment: Yup.
I think this might be a bug with discord.js v13 and will probably be fixed soon in the future, unless I'm somehow importing discord functions incorrectly

Comment: you are using the async/await system, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried like this?

```
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Role_Name")
member.roles.add(role)

var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "Role_Id")
member.roles.add(role)
```

Comment: I am able to find the role just fine, the problem is specifically with the `member.roles.add(role)` part.

Comment: Do you still get error with that code line? Weird. I'm using that code line and works perfectly fine

Comment: When I add `cache` i get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')`

Answer (score -1):

When doing anything with roles, and most stuff in general, you need to access it via the `cache`, for example:

```
  function hasRole(member, roleID) {
      return member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === roleID);
  }
```

Comment: you didn't even use cache in the answer.

Comment: mb, u still know what to do

Comment: i removed my -1 because you improved it, but you also need to fetch sometimes, see my answer

Comment: I tried it, and I got `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')` back

Comment: As @Borisonekenobi points out, you should first ensure that cache is an array, to then call the `.some` method on, otherwise you'll get a `TypeError`. With EcmaScript 7, a `.?` is sufficient. `member.roles.cache?.some...`

Comment: I read through the documentation for discord.js v13 and it seems like they've removed `.cache`, which would mean that it would always return undefined

Comment: You should not use cache, as you never know whether any user is going to be in cache., making it unpredictable. If you do use cache, you should always include a failsafe which directly fetches the user.